# prepareForSegue what is the issue in my code, it does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

here is my code, i do not know what is wrong
anyone can help me?
thanks you.
this is the code in `prepareForSegue` method

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (self.keyWord.text.length > 0) {
        NSString * keyWord =self.keyWord.text;
        sqlite3 * database;
        sqlite3_open([[self dbPath] UTF8String], &database);
        const char * selectSQL = "select * from word_inf where word like ?";
        sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
        int queryResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, selectSQL, -1, &stmt, nil);
        NSMutableArray * result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if (queryResult == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%%",keyWord] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                int word_id = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
                char * word = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1);
                char* detail = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2);
                MyWord * wordObj = [[MyWord alloc] initWithId:word_id word:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:word] detail:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:detail]];
                [result addObject:wordObj];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
        DicTableViewController* resultViewController = (DicTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        resultViewController.wordArray = [result copy];
    }
}
```

this is the code in `cellForRowAtIndecPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    MyWord * wordObj = [self.wordArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITextField * word = (UITextField * )[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UITextField * detail =(UITextField * )[cell viewWithTag:2];
    word.text = wordObj.word;
    detail.text = wordObj.detail;

    return cell;
}
```

the issue is that it cannot turn to `TableView`, i do not know what wrong with it.
i guess there is something wrong in the code of `prepareForSegue`, maybe the `wordArray` did not get the value, but i am sure that `result` has value, anyone can help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxVzL.png)

```
2017-02-23 10:01:14.549546 note[2625:66178] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:14.552413 note[2625:66178] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:14.568519 note[2625:66161] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:14.588178 note[2625:66108] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:14.679790 note[2625:66108] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:18.909319 note[2625:66108] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:18.910011 note[2625:66108] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Gesture, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:18.910748 note[2625:66108] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:18.911257 note[2625:66108] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureExclusion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:24.476483 note[2625:66108] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/easerliu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D586AACB-7D56-47D9-9570-AF908DD3C8C8/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-02-23 10:01:24.476789 note[2625:66108] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2017-02-23 10:01:24.504921 note[2625:66108] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: Observer, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:24.505283 note[2625:66108] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: Workspace, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:24.505559 note[2625:66108] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: Trace, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:26.054137 note[2625:66108] subsystem: com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-02-23 10:01:27.210 note[2625:66108] -[UITableViewCellContentView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb291d04220
2017-02-23 10:01:27.213 note[2625:66108] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb291d04220'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a87034b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109eb421e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a8dff34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a7f5c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a7f5798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   note                                0x0000000109798cd4 -[DicTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 356
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010ae00ba9 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 757
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010ae00e07 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010add4871 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3295
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ae0a189 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 110
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010adf09e3 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ad58344 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f3a3cdc -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f3977a0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f39761e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f32562c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f352713 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010acbe878 _afterCACommitHandler + 346
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a814e17 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a814d87 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a7f9b9e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a7f9494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e4a3a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010ac93f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    24  note                                0x000000010979a3bf main + 111
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c63068d start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Help yourself. Debug!

Comment: well thank you, maybe i need to realize what is debug and how to use it at first. haha

Comment: Use custom cell classes, don't use `viewWithTag`.  One of your tagged views is the cell's content view, not a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this expression: `cell viewWithTag:1`. You accidentally assigned the tag 1 to the wrong view in your storyboard. Instead of (or in addition to) assigning it to the text field, you assigned it to the cell's content view.

Comment: but in fact i add 2 UITextField in the storyboard, and set tag as 1 and 2.

Comment: thank you i know the issue, in my storyboard  TableView's tag is also 1, now the issue is fixed, thanks.

Comment: by the way, can you tell me how you find the error, through the code? or other things. i always do not know how to find issue.